# Cambiar de activity al cerrar anuncio admob en Android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, admob

Estoy intentando que en mi proyecto se muestre un anuncio intersticial pero que cuando el usuario lo cierre, cambie de activity. Según he visto se hace desde `onAdDismissedFullScreenContent()` pero no me hace nada, ni siquiera me salta el TAG. Lo tengo de la siguiente forma:

```
mInterstitialAd?.fullScreenContentCallback = object: FullScreenContentCallback() {
        override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Ad was dismissed.")
            startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, ResultActivity::class.java))
        }

        override fun onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(adError: AdError?) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Ad failed to show.")
        }

        override fun onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Ad showed fullscreen content.")
            mInterstitialAd = null
        }
    }
```

¿Es correcto o se debe usar otra función?

Edit: Función actualizada con implementación de adListener, que da error de "unresolve reference":

```
fun cargarAnuncio(adRequest: AdRequest){
    InterstitialAd.load(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712", adRequest, object : InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
        override fun onAdLoaded(interstitialAd: InterstitialAd) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Ad was loaded.")
            mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd
        }

        override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {
            Log.d("TAG", adError?.message)
            mInterstitialAd = null
        }
    })

    mInterstitialAd?.fullScreenContentCallback = object: FullScreenContentCallback() {
        override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Ad was dismissed.")

        }

        override fun onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(adError: AdError?) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Ad failed to show.")
        }

        override fun onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Ad showed fullscreen content.")
            mInterstitialAd = null
        }
    }

    mInterstitialAd?.adListener = object: AdListener(){
        override fun onAdClosed() {
            super.onAdClosed()
            startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, ResultActivity::class.java))
        }
    }
}
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Usa [**FullScreenContentCallback**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/FullScreenContentCallback) que es un Callback que se invoca cuando los anuncios se muestran y se quitan en pantalla completa.

```
    override fun onAdLoaded(interstitialAd: InterstitialAd) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Ad was loaded.")
        mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd

        if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
            mInterstitialAd?.show(this@MainActivity)
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet.")
        }


        /*------------ Detecta cierre de anuncio---------------*/
        mInterstitialAd?.fullScreenContentCallback = object: FullScreenContentCallback() {
            override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                super.onAdDismissedFullScreenContent()
                //Se cierra anuncio, abre Activity
                startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, ResultActivity::class.java))
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Lo implemento pero me marca error en rojo la parte de ".adListener", como que no existe, mientras que onAdClosed() sí me lo reconoce sin problemas.

Comment: Pon el puntero del mouse arriba de lo que se muestra en rojo para que veas exactamente que marca. Tal vez debes usar mInterstitialAd?.

Comment: "unresolved Reference" pone. También he hecho el import mediante "import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener" y he puesto el interrogante, pero nada.

Comment: @PacoPepe actualice la respuesta, con este callback puedes lograr lo que deseas, revisa la otra respuesta que actualice también, espero tu apoyo, saludos!